# Error sending transaction to create ATA

Tags: anchor, web3.js, spl-token, solana-wallet-adapter

I am trying to create ATA of a user using my own account and send custom tokens to that ATA.
Using the following code:

```
  const recieverATA = await getAssociatedTokenAddress(
    tokenMintAddress,
    recieverPublicAddress
  );

  let createRecATA = new Transaction().add(
    createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction(
      wallet.pubkey,
      recieverATA,
      recieverPublicAddress,
      tokenMintAddress
    )
  );


 const trx = await sendTransaction(createRecATA,connection);
```

I am getting the following error:

```
 Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString')
    at PhantomWalletAdapter.sendTransaction (adapter.ts:233:1)
    at async WalletProvider.tsx:283:1
    at async awardCustomToken (utils.js:725:1)
    at async _awardCustomToken (App.js:317:1)
```

Is there any way to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue in the code was that I was using wallet.pubkey instead of wallet.publicKey.

Answer (score 0):

How about to check ATA already exist?

```
export async function accountExists(
    provider: Provider,
    account: PublicKey,
    programId: PublicKey = TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID): Promise<boolean> {
    const info = await provider.connection.getAccountInfo(account);
    return !(info === null || !info.owner.equals(programId));
}

....

const tx = new web3.Transaction();
if(!(await accountExists(provider, recieverATA)) {
  tx.add(createAssociatedTokenAccountInstruction(...));
}

...
const trx = await sendTransaction(createRecATA,connection);
```

Comment: I have checked this. the ATA is not created for the account

Answer (score 0):

Change the last line to:

```
const trx = await anchor.web3.sendAndConfirmTransaction(
   createRecATA, connection, [`wallet`])
```

The third argument for this transaction are its signers. Here we add wallet as a signer because it pays for and signs the creation of the ATA.

Comment: Got the following error

TypeError: connection.sendTransaction is not a function
    at Module.sendAndConfirmTransaction (send-and-confirm-transaction.ts:31:1)
    at _awardCustomToken (App.js:506:1)